# Multiple string parse to loop

Tags: perl

I currently have some code which returns a sites header content back:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
require IO::Socket; 

my @header; 
my $host = shift;

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
    PeerAddr => $host, 
    PeerPort => 80, 
    Proto => 'tcp') || die "Could not Connect $!\n"; 

print "Connected.\n"; 
print "Getting Header\n"; 

print $socket "GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n"; 
my $i = 0; 
while (<$socket>) { 
    @header[$i] = $_; 
    $i++; 
} 

$i = 0;
print "--------------------------------------\n"; 
while ($i <= 8) { 
    print "@header[$i++]"; 
} 

print "-------------------------------------\n"; 
print "Finished $host\n";
```

What I would like to do, is to be able to read from a file open (FILE, '<', shift); and then every IP in the file, to pass into a the header retrieve loop, which saves me from manually doing one by one.

What I mean by this is to have a file containing (example ips): 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 on each line and then parsing all of them through the get header function.

Comment: You should really add `use warnings` and tidy up all the warnings you'll get when you run your code again. Doing things like `@header[$i] = $_` probably isn't what you want to do.

Comment: Just to point out there is a subtle error with the creation of $socket using `||` as described by @Ilmari Karonen here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9221648/1190901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
my @header; 
my $host = shift;
...
```

with

```
while (<>) {
   chomp( my $host = $_ );
   my @header; 
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would just open your file, read the contents into a list, then iterate over the list:

```
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "$!";
my @ips = <$fh>;
close $fh;
foreach my $ip ( @ips ) {
   chomp $ip;
   ...
}
```