# Scalar value errors (with IO::Socket)

Tags: perl

This is my current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
require IO::Socket;

while (<>) {
        chomp(my $host = $_);
        my @header;

        print "Connecting to: $host\n";
        my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
                PeerAddr => $host,
                PeerPort => 80,
                Proto => 'tcp') || print "Could not connect: $!\n";

        print "Connected.\n";

        print $socket "GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n";
        my $i = 0;
        while (<$socket>) {
                @header[$i] = $_;
                $i++;
        }

        $i = 0;
        print "--------------------------------------\n";
        while ($i <= 8) {
                print "@header[$i++]";
        }

        print "-------------------------------------\n";
        print "Finished $host\n\n";
}
```

If while going through a list of IP's, and a host is down, instead of continuing onto the next IP, it will give me an error "Can't use string ("1") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use".

If I then change @header[$i] = $*; to $header[$i] = $*; I also get the same error. How can I make this script better.

Comment: What line is causing the error?  Also, you should probably either `die` or move on to the next argument if the creation of `$socket` as a new `IO::Socket::INET` object isn't successful.

Comment: `@header[$i]` is incorrect even if changing it to the right thing doesn't fix the error.

Comment: @Wooble - Good catch.  Yet another reason why the `warnings` pragma should always be enabled.

Comment: It says line 18 is causing the error. And @Wooble, I was using die, until I saw the problem that if it finds ANY hosts that are down, it will exit, I need it to carry on, to the next one if a host is down, so I used print. Warnings are enabled #!/usr/bin/perl -w

Comment: Don't just say "line 18". Say which line that is. Line 18 if I count it out is `print $socket ...`

Comment: @TLP, sorry, but yes, that is line 18.

Comment: Then put that into an [`eval` block](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) and then check the value of `$@`.

Comment: @TLP: No they don't. Errors in multi-line statements may sometimes be reported as occurring on the first line of the statement, but Perl _does_ know how to count lines correctly.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yeah, I started feeling unsure about that one too.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is in the way you set `$socket`:

```
my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
        PeerAddr => $host,
        PeerPort => 80,
        Proto => 'tcp') || print "Could not connect: $!\n";
```

Since you're using the `||` operator, which has higher [precedence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity) than `=`, this statement is parsed as

```
my $socket = (new IO::Socket::INET(...) || print ...);
```

If `new IO::Socket::INET` returns a false value (as it does if the connection fails), the `print` will be executed *and* its return value (which is normally `1`) will be assigned to `$socket`.
When you then try to use `$socket` as an [indirect object](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax) in the statement:

```
print $socket "GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n";
```

Perl notices that the value `1` is not actually an object reference and throws the error you reported.

If you'd  used the low-precedence operator `or` instead of `||`, the value of `$socket` would've been `undef` instead of `1`, and the error message you'd have received would've been something like `Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference ...`.  Of course, this wouldn't have actually fixed your problem, but at least it might've made it easier to diagnose.

To actually fix the problem, you need to fix your code so that you won't keep executing the rest of the loop body if the connection fails.  One way to do that would be like this:

```
my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
        PeerAddr => $host,
        PeerPort => 80,
        Proto => 'tcp');

unless ($socket) {
        print "Could not connect: $!\n";
        next;  # skip the rest of the loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the simple solution be to use the lower precedence version 'or' which has lower precedence than '='?

```
my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
    PeerAddr => $host,
    PeerPort => 80,
    Proto => 'tcp')
        or print "Could not connect: $!\n";
```

In fact, the operators 'or', and 'xor', have the lowest operator precedence (see perlop).